# Why does VideoCapture in OpenCV 4.0.1 not work in my Anaconda environment in Windows 10?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision, anaconda, video-capture

When I run the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
      print("Unable to read camera feed")
```

My output is:
Unable to read camera feed

Comment: What `ffmpeg` version are you using? You should get 4.1 from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: @aergistal I downloaded the 4.1 static version from your link and copied the ffmpeg file from      ffmpeg-20190202-b429c86-win64-static\bin to    C:\Users\xyz\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlow-GPU-Keras\Lib\site-packages and still get the same output.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try to [capture](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam) directly with `ffmpeg` and report the results.

Comment: @aergistal After I downloaded the ffmpeg from your link, I just had to enable my webcam by pressing Fn + F6. Now VideoCapture works for both webcam and uploading video files. Thanks for the link!